# List View after DateMenu shows all newsitems, instead of only items of selected year/month

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-8.7.x

request uri: id=55&tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Byear%5D=2016&tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Bmonth%5D=10&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&cHash=36b4a3a8303b04f2c15c193b6a338b10&no_cache=1

Selection on year (= 2016) and month (= 10), but the news extension does nothing with these selectionitems. Result: all the newsitems are shown.

What must I do to activate the selection?

Answer (score 0):

You should uncheck option

"Disable override demand"

in news-plugin tab "additional".
Thats works for me.

Comment: in news-plugin "list view" !