# tx_news 6.3.0 and datemenu

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I use TYPO3 8.7.4 with tx_news 6.3.0 and try to set up an archive with a date menu. My structure is the following:

```
- News
-- Detail page
-- Archive
```

The date menu and all articles are shown on the "News" page correctly and in the date menu plugin the page "Archive" is set as list page. When I click on an datemenu-entry ("Januar 2018" for example), all news articles are shown on the "Archive"-page and not only the ones from January 2018.

Google couldn't help me and I tried several configurations. I also looked at the standard typoscript setup but didn't find any configuration options. Of course I checked the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/UsersManual/Plugins/Index.html#date-menu) but to my mind I didn't something different...

**Update:**

URLs in date menu look like this:

```
/news/archiv/?tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Byear%5D=2017&tx_news_pi1%5BoverwriteDemand%5D%5Bmonth%5D=11&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&cHash=fff01ee47ff40525b2223cad75bad408
```

What might be the problem here? Do you need more info to help me? Is there a detailed tutorial I didn't find?

Thx & kind regards,
Christian

Comment: is `plugin.tx_news.settings.disableOverrideDemand` enabled for you? see [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Configuration/TypoScript/Index.html#disableoverridedemand)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ: Thx for trying to help!
No, I didn't set this option, and setting it to "0" or "1" doesn't have any effect. I added an url of my date menu in my question.

Comment: as you use cHash be sure all parameters are in the cHash included. otherwise. in such URLs the cHash defines the valid parameters, others will be removed. (you problem sounds like a vital parameter gets lost)

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ: I use standard configuration (to my mind). Did you mean I have to set `[FE][cHashRequiredParameters] = 'tx_news_pi1[news],tx_news_pi1[controller],tx_news_pi1[action]'` in InstallTool? I did now, but it has no effect...

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ: Problem solved, see below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the right way to post my solution:

The problem solved! @BerndWilkeπφ gave me the hint in his first answer, but obviously changing this option in typoscript didn't have any effect.

After finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48298362/list-view-after-datemenu-shows-all-newsitems-instead-of-only-items-of-selected) I changed the language in the TYPO3-backend to english and found the option "Disable override demand" in the "additional" tab. After unchecking this option, the archive list shows only the articles of the corresponding month.

Comment: if you need to **uncheck** the plugin option, there probably is an error in the handling. you should open a bug-ticket for the extension.